# Is there a Django decorator to prevent mutating underlying object?

Tags: python, django

Is there a Django @decorator I can attach to a model's method that would prevent that method from making any changes to the database?

I think of the right expression to Google for.

Answer (score 0):

You can use abstraction.

```
class Person(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

This won't reflect database.